# runtime Error 9 when opening excel workbook in a folder to copy specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to handle runtime error 9.
My goals is to create a new workbook that compile specific sheet (Master User) from all excel workbook in a folder.
I'm stuck while using "on error goto" because i don't get it how to set the program while error (sheet doesn't exist) goto next workbook.
My code now cause me stuck in an never ending loop on a workbook that didn't have "master user" sheet

```
Sub Master()
    Dim MyFiles As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim Filename As String
    
    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:="Master", FileFormat:=51
    Path = "D:\My Document\"
    myExtension = "*.xls*"
    MyFiles = Dir(Path & myExtension)
    
    On Error GoTo test

DoAgain:
    Do While MyFiles <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (Path & MyFiles)
      Sheets("master user").Select
      ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Copy
      Workbooks("Master.xlsx").Activate
      Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
      Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
      If InStr(MyFiles, ".") > 0 Then
   Filename = Left(MyFiles, InStr(MyFiles, ".") - 1)
End If
      ActiveSheet.Name = Filename
      Workbooks(Filename).Activate
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    MyFiles = Dir
    Loop
      Workbooks("Master.xlsx").Activate
      ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

test:
      ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Resume DoAgain

ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Place `Exit Sub` on the line before `test:` to stop the endless loop. Place `Activeworkbook.Save` before `Exit Sub`.

Comment: try that, but still stuck looping on the workbook without "master user" sheet. 
and suddenly stop looping but the "master" workbook stop creating new sheet from last endless looping workbook, eventhough there still +- 10 more workbook that have "master user" sheet

Comment: Comment out the error handler and `Resume DoAgain` line. Set a break point  at the beginning of your loop and step through your code with `F8` to see where the code errors. Note the error code you receive and debug from there.

Comment: In which workbook is the code located? To which location (path) are you saving `Master.xlsx`?

Comment: the code located in a xlsm file on other folder
i save the master.xlsx on the source folder.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Worksheet Ranges From Multiple Workbooks to a New Workbook

**The Workbooks**

1. The workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).
2. The source workbook i.e. each workbook (file) found in the source folder.
3. The destination workbook i.e. a newly added workbook that will be copied to.

**Description**

- This will copy the first row of a same-named worksheet of each workbook (file) found in a folder to a newly added (and renamed) worksheet (multiple) of a new workbook (one).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateMaster()
    Const ProcName As String = "CreateMaster"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Source
    Const sFolderPath As String = "D:\My Document\" ' maybe a missing 's'?
    Const sFilePattern As String = "*"
    Const sExtensionPattern As String = ".xls*"
    Const swsName As String = "Master User"
    ' Destination
    Const dFileName As String = "Master.xlsx"
    ' You never mentioned the destination path ('Master.xlsx') so I chose
    ' the same path as the path of the workbook containing this code.
    ' Omitting this path will lead to unexpected results (errors).
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    
    ' Check if the source folder exists.
    If Len(Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The folder '" & sFolderPath & "' doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Return the paths of the files of the source folder in a collection.
    Dim sFilePaths As Collection
    Set sFilePaths = CollFilePaths(sFolderPath, sFilePattern, sExtensionPattern)
    If sFilePaths Is Nothing Then ' no files found
        MsgBox "No '" & sExtensionPattern & "'- files found in folder '" _
            & sFolderPath & "'.", vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim sFilePath As Variant
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dwbCreated As Boolean
    
    ' Loop through the elements (file paths) of the collection.
    For Each sFilePath In sFilePaths
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
        ' Attempt to create a reference to the source worksheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set sws = swb.Worksheets(swsName)
        On Error GoTo ClearError
        If Not sws Is Nothing Then ' source worksheet exists
            ' Add a new worksheet/workbook.
            If dwbCreated Then ' destination workbook created
                Set dws = dwb.Worksheets _
                    .Add(After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count))
            Else ' destination workbook not created
                Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
                Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
                dwbCreated = True
            End If
            ' Attempt to rename the destination worksheet.
            On Error Resume Next
                dws.Name = Left(swb.Name, InStrRev(swb.Name, ".") - 1)
            On Error GoTo ClearError
            ' Copy source to destination.
            sws.Rows(1).Copy dws.Rows(1)
            Set sws = Nothing 
        'Else ' source worksheet doesn't exist
        End If
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next sFilePath
    
    If dwbCreated Then
        dwb.Worksheets(1).Activate
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath & dFileName, dFileFormat
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close
        MsgBox "Master created.", vbInformation, ProcName
    Else
        MsgBox "Non of the opened workbooks contained a worksheet " _
            & "named '" & swsName & "'.", vbExclamation, ProcName
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the paths of the files of a folder in a collection.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function CollFilePaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "*", _
    Optional ByVal ExtensionPattern As String = "*") _
As Collection
    Const ProcName As String = "CollFilePaths"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim foPath As String: foPath = FolderPath
    If Right(foPath, 1) <> pSep Then foPath = foPath & pSep
    
    Dim ePattern As String: ePattern = ExtensionPattern
    If Left(ePattern, 1) <> "." Then ePattern = "." & ePattern
    
    Dim fiName As String: fiName = Dir(foPath & FilePattern & ePattern)
    If Len(fiName) = 0 Then Exit Function
        
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection
    
    Do Until Len(fiName) = 0
        coll.Add foPath & fiName
        fiName = Dir
    Loop
    
    Set CollFilePaths = coll
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: try that, but when the program found a file without sheet master user. the program stop.
my expectation is, close the workbook then open the next workbook on the folder.

Comment: I've added this line:  `Set sws = Nothing `. Sorry.